# How to determine the true x y co-ord in a touch event (or mouse event) via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, touch, coordinates, offset

I've been working on touch events and have some code working quite nicely, until the canvas doesn't start at the top left corner. As soon as I add anything before it, the reported event is offset by the position of the canvas.

I determine this by drawing a circle around where the touch was. The circle is always offset by the offset of the canvas from top left corner of the screen.

Looking at the event for on touch start, I can see that there is a pageY available (within chrome, using usb debugging). But when I google it, it seems that it's not a part of the standard and there appears to be some contention that it may be depreciated (though I cannot find out one way or the other).

So my question is what is the best cross browser method to deal with this (main concerns are safari and chrome, ie webkit, firefox is a nice to have)?

The same issue occurs for mouse events, for which I created a [JSFiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/metalskin/DG4fb/1/). However I' not sure if the same attributes are available for mouse events and touch events.

I should note, I am aware that I can hard code the offset and the problem is solved, however I'm looking for a solution that uses the information at hand without requiring any hard wired code specific to my html.

To recreate the JSFiddle, the HTML, CSS and Javascript are as follows:

```
<div class="title"></div>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin: 0px;
}

canvas {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000;
}

.title {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #888;
}

.container {
  width:auto;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#777;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var onMouseDown = function(e) {
    draw(document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d'), e.clientX, e.clientY);
}

$(function () {
    document.getElementById('myCanvas').addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
});


function draw(ctx, x, y) {
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.offsetWidth; 
ctx.canvas.height = ctx.canvas.offsetHeight;      

  var radius = 50;
  var lineWidth = 15;
  var r = 255;
  var g = 75;
  var b = 75;
  var a75 = 0.05;

  var adj = Math.abs(lineWidth / 2);

  rad = radius + adj;

  var stop1 = (rad - lineWidth) / rad;
  var stop2 = 0;
  var stop3 = stop1 + (1 - stop1) / 2;
  var stop4 = 0;
  var stop5 = 1;

  stop2 = stop3 - (stop3 - stop1) / 2;
  stop4 = stop3 + (stop5 - stop3) / 2;

  var radgrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, rad);

  radgrad.addColorStop(stop1, 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ', 0)');
  radgrad.addColorStop(stop2, 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ', .4)');
  radgrad.addColorStop(stop3, 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ', 1)');
  radgrad.addColorStop(stop4, 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ', .4)');
  radgrad.addColorStop(stop5, 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ', 0)');

  ctx.fillStyle = radgrad;
  ctx.arc(x, y, rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/DG4fb/3/

You canvas's top and left is not `clientX == 0; clientY == 0;` so you need to calculate the offset. Where is your canvas's top left corner? It's its `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` plus its `offsetParent`'s value and its `offsetParent.offsetParent`'s value, and on and on. That's what the `recursiveOffsetLeftAndTop` function handles for you.

Comment: Thanks Cat Chen, that works nicely. Interestingly for the event on a mouse down there is the offsetX and offsetY, but for some strange reason they're not available for touch events. very frustrating.

Btw, there is a problem with your solution, it doesn't take into account when elements are off the visible screen. For example, in carousels there are divs left and right that are not visible. In my example it screws up on the X, but to be honest I can ignore it as it's only the Y that gives me grief. :-)

Comment: There's a small bug in my code. It doesn't calculate page scroll. See here for the correct answer: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position

Answer (score 0):

If we user PageX and PageY instead of the ClientX and ClientY, it worked perfectly in my case...

```
        var offsets = recursiveOffsetLeftAndTop(canvas);
        var x = evt.targetTouches[0].pageX - offsets.offsetLeft;
        var y = evt.targetTouches[0].pageY - offsets.offsetTop;
```

Thank you for the solution.